# Table is blank forever - loading page with ngRoute

Tags: html, angularjs, ngroute

I am using angular routers

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/comment/list', {
        templateUrl: 'commentList.htm',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
});
```

```
<td ng-show="btnUADetails" ng-click="loadPage('commentList', x.userName);">
           <a class="detailButton" href="#/comment/list"></a>                   
</td>
```

and here is my angular function

```
$scope.loadPage = function(pageId, id) {
     if (pageId == "commentList") {
         $scope.getServerData($scope.generateUrl(pageId, 'json', id)).then(function(result) {
             $scope.serverComment = result;
         });
     } else {
         //do something
     }
 }
```

Before $HTTP returns response html page loads and i am getting clean data in html table . Can i load this page after my functions returns result ? Or load html file first and load it again when functions returns result ?

Comment: You can use ng-if="result" and then show the result on page load

Comment: Do you get your data and does the view update with the new data? Your only problem is that the table is blank for a few moments?

Comment: nope my problem is that table is blank forever .page is loading before i got response using $HTTP

Comment: What is btnUADetails in your html? Where are u setting the value for it?

Comment: it is nothing ingore it  i declare just for user privilegies this variable is declarating in login function

Comment: If that varaible is false then u won't get anything on your view. You may want to update your question with more inputs like providing code commentList.htm and also maybe change your $scope.serverComment = result.data;

Comment: And if you want the above things to appear, you have either call the function $scope.loadPage() or use ng-init and initialise

Answer (score 0):

When the router changes routes, it destroys the $scope of the current view and creates a new $scope with a new instance of the controller.

Include any information the new view needs as query parameters in the new URL.

Change the link to include a parameter:

```
<td ng-show="btnUADetails" ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶l̶i̶c̶k̶=̶"̶l̶o̶a̶d̶P̶a̶g̶e̶(̶'̶c̶o̶m̶m̶e̶n̶t̶L̶i̶s̶t̶'̶,̶ ̶x̶.̶u̶s̶e̶r̶N̶a̶m̶e̶)̶;̶"̶ >
    <a class="detailButton" href="#/comment/list?id={{x.userName}}"></a>
</td>
```

Use the parameter in the controller:

```
app.controller("mainController", function($scope, $route) {
    this.$onInit = function() {
      if ($route.current.templateUrl == 'commentList.htm') {
         var pageId = 'comment';
         var id = $route.current.params.id;
         $scope.getServerData($scope.generateUrl(pageId, 'json', id))
           .then(function(result) {
             $scope.serverComment = result;
         });
      };
    };
});
```

In the above example, the new instance of the controller uses the current params of the router to load the necessary data.